# Can fastlane be set up in an environment other than macos ?

Tags: fastlane

does anybody know if fastlane can only be set up exclusively in macos environment? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use big parts of it on Linux and Windows as well.

Most of the iOS stuff will only work on macOS, as the tools being used in the background (`xcodebuild` etc.) are only available on macOS. But for example creating apps in the Apple Developer Console or uploading apps to App Store Connect will work on all operating systems.

(Fastlane is currently working on improving and stabilizing that support for other operating systems, so expect this to get better over time)

Comment: I want to use it for building and deploying Android apps, is this supported in either windows or linux?

Comment: Yes, all the Android functionality is fully supported on all operating systems. (If something doesn't work, please create an issue at the Fastlane GitHub repository)

Comment: I checked their official site for setting it up for android and the tutorial is for macos only. Do you have any tutorials in mind for setting it up for windows or linux?

Comment: hey I have just realized that you provided answers in this thread that I read before posting here. https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/11687 According to your saying I understand that fastlane isn't supported officially yet in other platforms. Am I wrong?

Comment: Following the official guides should bring you pretty far. If you have specific questions, create an issue at the fastlane repo and mention what OS you are using.
"According to your saying I understand that fastlane isn't supported officially yet in other platforms. Am I wrong?" No, there might still be some areas that do not work - and that has to be documented. As this hasn't happened yet, there is no "official support" for these platforms. But I am pretty confident that the most relevant stuff for you will work. If not, create an issue and I will do my best to make it work asap.

Comment: with all due respect, you are saying "Following the official guides should bring you pretty far". But the official guides don't contain even a notion of how I can install fastlane in another environment. If it is installed yes they are really helpful of setting it up further but, you see, I am stuck one step behind.

Comment: As I said, those platforms are not _officially_ supported yet - which is why they are not mentioned in the docs. But it really is simple: 1. Download and install ruby from https://rubyinstaller.org/ 2. Execute `gem install fastlane -NV` (as mentioned in the docs, just without `sudo`) 3. Continue with https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/#setting-up-fastlane

Answer (score 0):

You can use "parts" of Fastlane on Windows, for example is not possible of doing screenshots and, of course, anything related to iOS.
You'll probably have to do use some Ubuntu subsystem or a docker if you want to work with Windows.
You should have no problem in Linux.

Comment: Fastlane should actually be almost as usable on Windows as it is on Linux. (I worked on and keep working on that.)